# ASP.NET button doesn't execute function RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am experiencing some troubles with the use of a button on a GridView controller on ASPX. I just can't make it work.

Here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="tablaPgos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="tablaPgos_RowCommand">
    <columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="idpago" HeaderText="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fechapago" HeaderText="Fecha de Pago" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="codigoestudiante" HeaderText="Codigo del Estudiante" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre" HeaderText="Tipo de Pago" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="monto" HeaderText="Monto" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acciones">
            <itemtemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnEliminar" runat="server" Text="Eliminar Pago" CommandName="Eliminar" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
            </itemtemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The data loads perfect, I use an API to load the data:

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CargarTabla();
}

protected async Task CargarTabla()
{
     string apiUrl = "http://localhost:5000/api/get/pagos";

     try
     {
         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
         HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;

         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             string jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
             List<ListadoPagos> pagos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ListadoPagos>>(jsonResponse);
             tablaPgos.DataSource = pagos;
             tablaPgos.DataBind();
         }
         else
         {
             // Manejar errores si la solicitud no es exitosa
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex);
     }
}
```

I have a button on the gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acciones">
    <itemtemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEliminar" runat="server" Text="Eliminar Pago" CommandName="Eliminar" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When I click it, I need it to make a delete request to the API, but it doesn't work. It doesn't show me any error or anything, it seems like the button doesn't even call the function.

Here is what I've been trying to do:

```
protected async void tablaPgos_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.CommandName == "Eliminar")
      {
          int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

          int id = Convert.ToInt32(tablaPgos.DataKeys[rowIndex]["idpago"]);
          await EliminarPagoAsync(id);
      }
}
```

```
private async Task EliminarPagoAsync(int idPago)
{
    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            string apiUrl = $"http://localhost:5000/api/delete/pago/{idPago}";

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.DeleteAsync(apiUrl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                lblMensaje.Text = "Pago eliminado exitosamente.";
                CargarTabla();
            }
            else
            {
                lblMensaje.Text = "Error al eliminar el pago. Por favor, intente nuevamente.";
                CargarTabla();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMensaje.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

As I said, the button doesn't even call the function. I tried setting the text of a label just to make sure that the problem wasn't the button, but the message doesn't show when I click it, so I'm assuming the problem is the button and not the API or something else :(

```
protected async void tablaPgos_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Eliminar")
    {
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        lMensaje.Text = "Button Pressed";
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful if you can help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        CargarTabla();
    }    
}
```

stop the bind happing on every post back (button click ect)